# How to Use defineAttributes To Specify NOT NULL and DEFAULT '1' in MySQL Record

Tags: plugin-development, database

How to Use defineAttributes  To Specify NOT NULL and DEFAULT '1' in MySQL Record

I am porting a plugin from another framework and it has the following
MySql tables structure. Is there an easy way to create the same
table structure within craft plugin?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_shortcut_shortcuts` (
`shortcut_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`site_id` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
`entry_id` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`field_id` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`autogenerated` char(1) NOT NULL default 'y',
`shortcut` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
`full_url_model` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`full_url` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`entry_date` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
`edit_date` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`shortcut_id`),
INDEX (`shortcut`)
) ;;

namespace Craft;

class ShortcutRecord extends BaseRecord
{
    public function getTableName()
    {
        return 'shortcut_shortcuts';
    }

    public function primaryKey()
    {
       return 'shortcut_id';
    }

    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return array(
            'shortcut_id' => array(AttributeType::Number, 'column' => ColumnType::PK),
            'site_id' => array(AttributeType::Number, 'column' => ColumnType::TinyInt),
```

I see how to add TinyInt. How do I specify NOT NULL and default '1'?

Answer (score 3):

For `NOT NULL` use `'required' => true` and to default to 1 use `'default' => 1`.